# How to use regular expressions to match gzinflate(base64_decode(

Tags: php, regex

I'm writing the Yara rules.
I tried using regular expression matching to remove the gzinflate(base64_decode(.
But in PHP, function names can be concatenated with strings.
Just like this

```php
eval("\$x=gzin"."flate(base"."64_de"."code()));
```

There are various ways of stitching.
Except for trying to match `"."` after every letter.
Is there a better solution?
Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array, then implode it:

```php
$array = ["\$x=gzin", "flate(base", "64_de", "code()"];

$str = implode($array);
```